# Why is this link to an item in iTunes not opening the music store from my application?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I need a user of my application to purchase and download music from iTunes to their iPhone.

I used the following code:

```
NSString *text=@"<a href=\"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/sports/id14659264?ign-mpt=uo%3D4\" target=\"itunes_store\"><img src=\"http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/images/web/linkmaker/badge_itunes-lrg.gif\" alt=\"Esperanza - Esperanza Spalding\" style=\"border: 0;\" /></a>";
[webview loadHTMLString:text baseURL:nil];
```

but the iTunes music store is not opening.  What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is just displaying an image link in a UIVebView.

If you want to open the iTunes app you can do this:

```
NSString *link = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/sports/id14659264";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

Comment: hi, I am using this one. But it showing one error. The request Could not be completed. What error is there. Shall i need any api for this to implement. Please help me.

Comment: This should work, try removing the parameters in your URL after the "?"

Comment: What it looks like he is doing is creating an HTML page in a UIWebView that has a linked image that, when tapped, will open the iTunes link.

Comment: @Velmurugan Check that you are not using country code on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, you will not be able to run it on the Simulator though.

Comment: correct. thanks. I found my problem. This link is not got authorized to download in India.